# Completions of Stalks of a Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

Let $S$ be a surface (so a $2$-dimensional proper $k$-scheme). My question arises from following another [thread of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331251/intuition-behind-rdp-rational-double-points).

I'm looking for conditions for $S$ which garantee that the completion of every stalk $O_{S,s}$ with respect to it's unique max ideal $m_s$ has the shape $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{S,s}= k[[x,y,z]]/(f_s)$.

The structure of $f_s$ might be depend on if $s$ is regular or singular. More precisely I intuitively expect that if $s$ is regular then $f_s$ is linear and therefore without loss of generality $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}= k[[x,y,z]]/(f)\cong k[[x,y]]$. Otherwise $f\in m_s ^n $ for $n\neq1$.

Comment: $f$ may be in $m_S^3$, for example, a triple point. I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Mohan: Yes, you are right. I modified the question. Essentially I'm asking under which conditions for the surface $S$ the completions of all stalks (of closed points) are of the form $O_{S,s}^{\wedge}= k[[x,y,z]]/(f_s)$.

Comment: The obvious condition is that embedding dimension is at most three.

Comment: @Mohan: Could you recommend a reference where is rigorously proved or sketch the idea? My starting point is the Cohen strucure theorem which just states that $O_{X,x}^{\wedge} \cong \Lambda [[x_1, \ldots , x_ n]]/I$ where $\Lambda$ is the Cohen ring. So the natural question is when $\Lambda=k$ and $I$ is principal?

Comment: The $n$ in your statement is the embedding dimension of the local ring, so if it is at most three, the completion would be either $k[[x_1,x_2]]$ or $k[[x_1,x_2,x_3]]/f$.

Comment: @Mohan: Assumining that embedding dim of $O_{S,s} \le 3$ holds,how do you exclude the case $k[[x_1,x_2,x_3]]/I=  O_{S,s}$ for $I=(f,g)$? Krull's PIT seems not really help here...

Comment: $O_{S,s}$ is  dimension two, so $I$ has height one. All height one prime ideals are principal.